# Using DataFlow to read data from Compute Engine

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-dataflow

I want to read data from MariaDB on Google Compute Engine and to write data to BigQuery by DataFlow but I always get the exception as below when I run the DataFlow program on DataFlowRunner.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Could not connect to address=(host=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)(port=3306)(type=master) : connect timed out)

1. I can access successfully the MariaDB by DBeaver.
2. I can run successfully the DataFlow program on DirectRunner.

Can give me some ideals, Thanks.

Comment: can you provide some more information?

For example the full exception and what command line you are trying to run and etc?

Comment: Hi Lara, Thanks for you response, we find the cause - firewall configuration.
another question, how do we set the firewall rule to allow jobs of DataFlow to access the Database on Compute Engine more security.

Comment: The database is on other ComputeEngine runs? I think you need to allow access to the service account that the Dataflow jobs run under to access that resource.

Comment: Hi Lara, Thank you.
Yes, our data source is a MySQL on a Compute Engine and we use DataFlow to read and then write data to BigQuery, both GCE and DataFlow under the same project.
1) Can we apply the VPC networks to both GCE and DataFlow to allow DataFlow to access GCE? now we try to do this method.
2) Do your mean let our GCE only can be accessed by a service account? 
3) I can't find the document with sample codes how to implement a service account in DataFlow. we will use AirFlow to manage the DataFlow. our beam version is 2.3.0.

Comment: Using service account and internal IP in dataflow and the firewall rule by service account solved this question, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To restrict it so that only Dataflow jobs can access it you can leverage the fact that Dataflow's harness VMs are created with the `dataflow` tag. Otherwise, you can allocate the GCE instance and DF workers on a specific network/subnetwork.

For example, create a GCE instance with a network tag such as `mariadb` so it can be used as the target to apply firewall rules to and/or select a specific VPC network/subnetwork. Install MariaDB (another option is to use an initialization script or a preinstalled solution through Cloud Launcher).

For the firewall rules, you'll need the Database to be reachable on port `tcp:3306`. For the GCE instance (target tag `mariadb`) you'll need to allow ingress traffic from either source tags `dataflow` or coming from within the subnetwork on the aforementioned port. Take into account that, for the latter option, you'll need to also allow internal communication between DF workers inside the subnetwork.

Now, on the Dataflow side, add the `JdbcIO` and `mariadb` connector dependencies to the `pom.xml`file:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.beam/beam-sdks-java-io-jdbc -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
    <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-io-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mariadb.jdbc/mariadb-java-client -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.7</version>
</dependency>
```

A sample Dataflow snippet to connect (use internal IP in the JDBC connection string if using the subnetwork approach):

```
public class MariaDB {

  public static void main(String[] args) { 
    PipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation().as(PipelineOptions.class);
    Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);

    PCollection<String> account = p.apply(JdbcIO.<String>read()
.withDataSourceConfiguration(JdbcIO.DataSourceConfiguration.create("org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver", "jdbc:mariadb://INTERNAL_IP:3306/database").withUsername("root").withPassword("pwd"))
    .withQuery("SELECT … FROM table")
        .withCoder(SerializableCoder.of(String.class))
    .withRowMapper(new JdbcIO.RowMapper<String>() {
                public String mapRow(ResultSet rs) throws Exception {
...
                }}
    ));

  p.run();
  }
}
```

And launch the job specifying the subnetwork and matching zone if needed:

```
mvn compile exec:java \
      -Dexec.mainClass=com.example.MariaDB \
      -Dexec.args="--project=PROJECT_ID \
      --stagingLocation=gs://BUCKET_NAME/mariadb/staging/ \
      --output=gs://BUCKET_NAME/mariadb/output \
      --network="dataflow-network" \
      --subnetwork="regions/europe-west1/subnetworks/subnet-europe-west" \
      --zone="europe-west1" \
      --runner=DataflowRunner"
```

Comment: very thanks for your complete answer and it is useful. we will implement this.